# Stop stdin while command is running

Tags: linux, command-line, stdin, ash

How to stop `stdin` while command is running in `ash` (not `bash`)?

For example:

1. `sleep 10`
2. type `echo hello` while `sleep` is still running
3. observe `hello` is in `stdout` after `sleep` finishes

Desired:

1. `sleep 10`
2. type `echo hello` while `sleep` is still running
3. observe shell as if nothing was typed in while `sleep` was running

I expect the solution would be something like: `tput <stop stdin>; sleep 10; tput <restart stdin>; <enter>`

This will not be in a shell script (only needs to work with interactive shell).

Comment: Is the `sleep 10` a placeholder for some other command? If so, will that command read from standard input, and would you need to stop it from doing so?

Comment: It's a placeholder program that will not read from `stdin`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stty -echo` disable the echo of your terminal, but if you type something, it will be memorized and the shell will get the typed key.

Then, before leaving, `stty echo` (revert back the echo mode), and drain the terminal input with this program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main(void)
{
    tcflush(0, TCIFLUSH);
    return 0;
}
```

The whole thing would be `stty raw -echo;sleep 10;stty sane;./my_program`.

Using raw, avoid CtrlC CtrlZ to interfere. Sane imply echo and revert the terminal to a sane mode.

Comment: With zsh, you can do `STTY='raw -echo' sleep 10`. With other shells, you can always do `tty=$(stty -g); stty raw -echo; sleep 10; stty "$tty"`

Comment: See also `perl -MPOSIX -e 'tcflush(0,TCIFLUSH)'` (perl more likely to be available than a C compiler).

Comment: I'm wondering whether the OP wanted to suppress not the local terminal echo (or not *only* the local echo) but actually the *output* of the command: instead of `echo hello` consider `ls -l`.

Comment: The commands typed in while `sleep` is running should not run at all.

Comment: If you just type `sleep 10`, the shell will wait 10s, and **afterward** look at the tty buffer and can find something. If you type `sleep 10;./my_program`, the shell then `my_program`which empty the tty buffer, then there is nothing to execute.